# How can I check type of uploaded file that's security

Tags: php, security, file-upload

In php manual said that `$_FILES['userfile']['type']` is under control of the client(so maybe it can be edited,I guess).

[php manual.](http://us.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

> `$_FILES['userfile']['type']`
>   The mime type of the file, if the browser provided this information.
>  An example would be "image/gif".
>  This mime type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore don't take its value for granted.

and this:

> You could use the `$_FILES['userfile']['type']` variable to throw away any files that didn't match a certain type criteria, but use this only as first of a series of checks, because this value is completely under the control of the client and not checked on the PHP side.

So how can I check the type of uploaded file for preventing the harmful file to be uploaded?

Comment: what type of harmfull files do you want to check? malware, javascripts? As long as you don't run any files, serverside you would be save anyway right?

Comment: You've copy and pasted the exact way on how to check....

Comment: You've copy and pasted the exact way on how to check....

Comment: @joel harkes it can be someone upload php file and he find the path of the file. so it can be run by other people right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered for yourself, you should thoroughly check each file to avoid security issues.

Mostly it depends on what kind of files you want to allow. I'd go with these two steps:

**1. Check the content type.**

Nothing to add here, you've already posted the way to do it in your question. However, this can be faked, so please don't forget to ....

**2. Verify the file content.**

You should carefully check the files content. If you're dealing with images, you can use phps image functions to be on the safe side.

Example:

```
$x = getimagesize($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']);
if (isset($x)) {
    if($x['mime'] != 'image/gif' && $x['mime'] != 'image/jpeg') {
        echo 'Not a valid GIF or JPEG';
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really see how this would protect against anyone faking the headers or mime-types and proceeding to upload anything they wanted.

Comment: Boolean expressions are checked from left to right so `isset($x)` should be the first.

Comment: You can still embed PHP code in a perfectly valid image file. All that matters is how the server interprets the file on request. And that depends on the file’s name extension.

Comment: Its not about preventing to upload anything, its to make sure it doesn't get processed in a wrong way. Of course PHP code could still be embedded, and one has to take other precautions, too, like a proper server & php configuration, securing the upload folders and so on.